# Pandas resampling not working as expected

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

[Here's](https://github.com/lakegs/test/blob/master/data.pkl)  data.pkl and below is the code. I'm getting values for SMA20 but for SMA200 I am getting NaN. The data set is large enough to find the mean value of SMA200. What AM I goofing?

```
df = pd.read_pickle("data.pkl")
if not df.empty:    
    df = df.astype(dtype={"volume": "int32", "close": "float32",
                                 "date": 'datetime64[ns]'})        
    df.date = df.date - pd.Timedelta('-5 hours 30 min')    
    df.set_index('date', inplace=True, drop=True)            
    df = df.resample('5Min').agg({'close': 'ohlc', 'volume': 'sum'})   
    df3 = pd.merge(df['close'], df['volume'], on="date")        
    df3['SMA20'] = df3['close'].rolling(window=20).mean()
    df3['SMA200'] = df3['close'].rolling(window=200).mean()
```

Comment: cleaned the data  using df3.dropna(subset=['close'], inplace=True)  and it worked as expected